# ADB error : Unable to connect

Tags: android, adb

I'm working on Ubuntu so i want to debug my android application via wireless connection.

It was working well but now i'm not able to connect to my tablet and I don't know why is.

The only thing that I know, **if I use another network, I can connect to my tablet**.

Is there any network settings that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all things but anyone didn't work.
Eventually, I thought my problem was a network issue so I fixed my problem by resetting modem settings.

Answer (score 0):

Is your IP address, netmask and gateway are correct both side ? Can you ping both side ?

If it's working on another network, it should be a network issue.

Comment: yes they were correct both side and I'm sure that two devices in same network